# Maintain fragment state along with views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragments. Fragment A- contains a ListView to show list of items fetched from API and Fragment B to show the detail of List item.The fragment C is a separate fragment.

Fragment A contains 100+ items which takes time during fetching from Api. 
When user comes on Fragment A, the Api call is fired (fetching records), Now after few seconds if user switch to Fragment C; it comes up and fragment A ondestroyView is called. Now when user comes back to Fragment A the api call is again fired. 
What i want to achieve is that if user comes back to Fragment A should not send the call again but it should keep continuing the last process or the fragment A must be keep processing its work flow if i have switch to Fragment C.

Can any body please suggest a good way to achieve this?

Comment: try to store your processing data when you moving to another fragment. when get back to the original one then, process stored data first then continue the process.

Comment: I think you can use flag to check your API call success. When returning from fragment C to fragment A, check if API call succeed and show results or whait until it completes. Also it depends on which way you do API call from AsyncTask or Service.

Comment: Try to use boolean status value . Means when you load the fragment first time make is true. and when your frgment ondestroy() is called make it false. And try to check this value every time the fragment is get loaded.

Comment: @Wishmaster I am using Asyntask. The thing is when i come to C from A my A's onDestroyView() is called and all processes associated are stopped . I need the fragment A to keep working if even i am on C

Comment: @Googler not quite onDestroyView() doesn't stop your asynctask. So you can cache data from this task as you wish.

Comment: @Wishmaster I know this. But is there any way to keep Fragment A live throughout app is running even if user switches to other fragments.

Comment: @Googler fragment A keep alive until onDestroy() method call. onDestroyView() method calls by system to prevent grow of memory usage because of useless visual data. But fragment A is still running and keeps its instance state.

Comment: `100+ items with a ListView` , i would never do that. use `RecyclerView` instead

Answer (score 0):

The base algorithm is:

1. Load data in separate thread.
2. Store it in db.
3. When load finished, generate an event(with [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for example).
4. Subscribe on this event and show the content with [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) when you need it.

So, you have thread-safe and configuration change-safe way to load, store and show the data without blocking main thread and unnecessary server calls.

Comment: Scanerio is to keep the Fragment A alive even if user switches to fragment C so when user get back to Fragment A it should see the published results fetched from Api in Fragment A

Comment: You should allow gc to punish and pardon any objects including fragments) Fragments should be able to be created and killed at any time: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html#Design

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data in an `IntentService`. When the data is fetched fire an event.

On your Activity (the father activity for your fragment A, B and C) listen for the event and store the fetched data within your activity.

On your activity, check if fragment A is visible. If it is visible, pass the data to your fragment.

This way you activity lifecycle will handle the availability of your data, e.g. as long as your activity is alive you don't need to fetch for the data again, which is what you are looking for I presume.

I didn't test this but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

PS; Don't use asynctasks. They are bad, **very bad**. [Check here why](http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/).
Try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for your network calls.

Comment: Yes, Your answer is near to my scenario. Can you please share any example of getting api data through intentservice and registering the event please